# Start the same "sessions" after shutdown

Tags: startup, reboot, init, autostart, restart

Many times it happen I got several terms & app sessions opened, while I just have to quick shutdown the machine to move away in another building.

Is there a way, when I next boot the laptop, to have back all my "UN-CLOSED" sessions (terms & apps), if I did shutdown without exit ?

( no freeze, no hibernate but real restart )

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to use standby (for short time inactivities) or hibernate (for longer ones), you could try to check the key

```
/apps/gnome-session/options/auto_save_session
```

in `gconf-editor`, but bear in mind that reopening the same apps (conversely to freeze/hibernate) do not take you to the same exact working desktop.

Moreover, I have to admit I have not tested the solution, so may not work.

Comment: unfortunately doesn't seem to work ..., may be becouse I saw some stop process errors during the shutdown but I didn't have the time to see what was about ...